# Структуры с++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, структуры

Создал стуктуру. Ввожу 2 элемента `f.vozrast`. Хочу распечатать, но печатает только второй введенный элемент `f.vosrast`.

```
struct sname
{
    char fio[256];
    int vozrast;
}; sname f;
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cin >> f.vozrast;
        cout << "Возраст:" << f.vozrast;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Видимо при вводу второго возраста результат перезаписывается на месте первого. Как Разделить `f.vozrast` на "массив" и можно было вывести по-элементно?

Comment: http://ideone.com/4ozWKd - выводит оба. Или вы считаете, что вы вводите фамилию и возраст в одну и ту же переменную? :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы не этого хотите?

```
struct sname
{
    char fio[256];
    int vozrast;
};

sname f[2];
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cin >> f[i].vozrast;
        cout << "Возраст:" << f[i].vozrast << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, именно этого. Почему sname f[2] конкретно 2? Потому что у меня 2 элемента в структуре?

Comment: Сколько надо - столько и делайте. Вы захотели 2 (`for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)`) - вот я два и написал. Хотите - делайте больше...